# How to have a static onclick parameter in HTML button?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I dynamically create HTML buttons, in Javascript, that when users click on them they call a same function, but with a different parameters.
For example:

```
function a(param){console.log(param);};

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   button = document.createElement('button');
   button.onclick = <place a function that when button is clicked, calls function a with parameter i>;
}
```

Can someone give me a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the `a` function:

```
button.setAttribute('data-param', i);
button.onclick = function () {a(this.getAttribute('data-param'));};
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/systemovich/asw3myqg/1/

Comment: @Fernando, fixed. Checkout the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
function b(param){
    var myParam = param;
    return function a() {
         console.log(myParam);
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   button = document.createElement('button');
   button.onclick = b(i);
}
```